# Test if variable contains circular references

Tags: php, circular-reference

**How do you test a variable for circular references?**

I am using PHP's `var_export()` function with the return string argument set to `true`.

I found that `Warning: var_export does not handle circular references` and was wondering if anyone knew of a way to test if a variable contains a circular reference so that I may use it before trying to use `var_export` on it.

I know that `var_export` outputs PHP eval-able text that can be used to recreate the array and even though I am not using it for that I still want to use this function when it is available because the output format meets my needs. `var_dump` is not an option because it doesn't accept an argument to return a string instead. I am aware that I could buffer the output of `var_dump` which handles circular references gracefully and save the buffer contents to a variable but I really just want to know if someone knows of a way to test for such references in a variable.

If you want to create a quick circular reference do this:

```
$r = array();
$r[] = &$r;
var_export($r, true);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would this do it?

```
function isRecursive($array) {
    foreach($array as $v) {
        if($v === $array) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: What version of php are you on? I run it in the interactive shell of 5.4 and it returns the expected result.

Comment: This will only check one level deep for this particual problem. For a true recursive check you'd have to call isRecursive() recursively at some point, but you also have to check *all* variables against all other variables in the nested tree. The computing complexity quickly explodes exponentially (no puns were harmed in making this comment).

Answer (score 6):

Hacky but returns true based on the circular example you gave:

```
<?php
// create the circular reference
$r = array();
$r[] = &$r;

function isRecursive($array){
  $dump = print_r($array, true);
  if(strpos($dump, '*RECURSION*') !== false)
      return true;
  else
      return false;
}

echo isRecursive($r); // returns 1
```

Interested to see what else people come up with :)