# Error - when getting text from pdf file using smalot pdf parser in codeigniter-4

Tags: php, fatal-error, codeigniter-4, pdfparser

I'm trying to upload a pdf file.
It can be password protected or not.

But I receive this error:

```sh
Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted on line ***print_r($pages);***
```

This however only happens on PDF files that aren't password protected. Although, the [*Smalot PDF parser*](https://github.com/smalot/pdfparser) works fine with password protected PDF files.

I already have a *helper method* `removePdfPassword()` for removing the password where necessary.

```php
    removePdfPassword($dir . $_FILES["bsfile"]["name"][$i],   $_REQUEST['pdfpassword'][$i], $dir .$file_name);
    include 'public/pdfparser/vendor/autoload.php';
    $parser     = new \Smalot\PdfParser\Parser();
    $location   = $dir . $file_name;
        
    echo "<pre>";
    $pdf        = $parser->parseFile($location);
    $pages      = $pdf->getPages();
    print_r($pages);
    die;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using print\_r and var\_dump with circular reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6292164/using-print-r-and-var-dump-with-circular-reference)

Comment: A bit late to the question but one way to handle this is using `qpdf --decrypt`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of printing the whole file's *pages* at once, try doing it in bits. I.e:

Instead of:

```php
// ...

 print_r($pages);

// ....
```

Use this:

```php
// ...

foreach ($pages as $page) {
    echo "<div>" . $page->getText() . "</div>";
}

// ...
```

Comment: Thanks @steven7mwesigwa.
That line is working for each and every pdf. Anyway that issue has been resolved.

Now I'm getting **Secured pdf file are not allowed**. Although pdf is not password protected.